# How to add an image which is on the screen to PDF (with Itextsharp)

Tags: image, itext

I need to add an image to a PDF using ItextSharp. I was able to do it when the image is on the server, but now a have an image on the screen and I don't know how to add it to the PDF.

This is the code to add image from the server :

```
logo = Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/Imagens/208/6633/20190621_095626.jpg"))
    cb = writer.DirectContent
    logo.ScaleToFit(200, 200)
    logo.SetAbsolutePosition(20, 250)
    doc.Add(logo)
```

This is what I have tryed, but I got an erro "Tha path is not correct" :

```
logo = Image.GetInstance(Image1.ImageUrl)
    cb = writer.DirectContent
    logo.ScaleToFit(200, 200)
    logo.SetAbsolutePosition(200, 250)
    doc.Add(logo)
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

I convert the code provide by Pavan to VB.NET (see below) but there is one error that I can not solve.

```
Dim converter As Drawing.ImageConverter = New Drawing.ImageConverter()
Dim b As Byte() = Converter.ConvertTo(Image1, GetType(Byte()))
Dim img As Image = New iTextSharp.text.Image(ImageDataFactory.create(b)) <==Here I got erro (new can not be used in a declared class 'Mustinherit')
img.ScaleToFit(200, 200)
img.SetAbsolutePosition(200, 250)
doc.Add(img)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `Image1` object available, you do not need to call `GetInstance()` again. Because the `GetInstance()` it self will return an `image`.

Either directly assign to some other object, or use it straight away, something like below (Not tested).

```
ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter(); 
byte[] b = converter.ConvertTo(Image1, typeof(byte[])); 
Image img = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(b));
img.ScaleToFit(200, 200)
img.SetAbsolutePosition(200, 250)
doc.Add(img)
```

Comment: Hello Pavan. I did what you sugest but I got an error saying "ScaleToFit is not a member of Image1"

Comment: Could you please tell me, what is the type of Image1

Comment: I have this  <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" /> to define the object

Comment: Got it . It is not Itext image. I will provide you an updated answer

Comment: Pavan.. I converted your code to VB.NET but I got an error that I don't know how to solve. Please see code above.

Comment: You are assigning to "Dim img As Image".... May be you need to change it to "Dim img As iTextSharp.text.Image". Could you please try that?

Comment: I tryed, but nothing change. The error is still there.